# Laravel 5.5 - $request->file returns null

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I have created a form that uploads a file but it returns a null value when I submit. When I add in the enctype="multipart/form-data" it reloads the page and doesn't seem to go through my controller.

MY HTML FORM

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="importform" method="POST" action="{{ route('import_type') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
<div class="controls">
<div class="control-group text-center">
  <label class="btn btn-primary" for="file-selector">
  <input id="file-selector" name="template_upload" type="file" value="" required autofocus style="display:none" onchange="$('#upload-file-info').html(this.files[0].name)" required>                                    Upload List               </label>
   <span class='label label-default' id="upload-file-info"></span>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="control-group">
   <div class="controls">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="import-submit" name="import-submit">
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

MY CONTROLLER: I am using the import method

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\ImportTypeRequest;
use \App\Guest;
use \App\Role;
use \App\User;
use \App\Type;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;



class GuestController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

        $user = User::with('roles')->where('id', Auth::id())->get();
        $types = Type::where('user_id', Auth::id())
            ->where('active',1)->get();


        return view('view_import',compact('user','types'));

    }

    public function import(ImportTypeRequest $request)
    {


        $template_upload = $request->file('template_upload');
        dd($template_upload);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share your route definition?

Comment: What is in `ImportTypeRequest`?

Comment: Can you try to replace ImportTypeRequest with default Request and check if it's working or not? and if it's working than you have something in your ImportTypeRequest which prevents the request to go into your import action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some suggested ways trying to solve this.

First of all in your import method add `dd($request->all())` at its top and see what's the response. You should see all your form data and of course `template_upload` file. That's how you make sure that you see all the coming data from your form to your controller method.

Then try to get rid of `ImportTypeRequest` and just use `Illuminate\Http\Request` to see what will you get. If you got different result then the problem is in `ImportTypeRequest` class.

Then why don't you just use `$request->template_upload`?! It's cleaner I guess.

Comment: Thank you it now works, There was a problem in my ImportTypeRequest. The rules in my Request file were not return my array.